# Is there a way to apply multiple method by one liner in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is an array like this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
```

I want to get the return values of `size` and `sum` like this.

```
size = a.size
sum = a.sum
```

Is there a way to get both values by a one-liner like this?

```
size, sum = a.some_method(&:size, &:sum)
```

Comment: There is no method `sum` defined on an array.

Comment: @sawa Ruby on Rails provides this function on `Enumerable`. Also, the OP might defined it. No reason for a downvote.

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke And, where did the OP mention Ruby on Rails or their own method?

Comment: @sawa he/she didn't, but I don't think that it matters for the question.

Comment: @Tetsu could you make more clear what your intention with calling two methods in one line is? As you see, there is speculation in the answers if you just want make the code shorter or if you want to avoid walking the array multiple times.

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke @sawa Sorry, that was my missunderstanding that `sum` is pure ruby method. I should have checked it. And I wanted to make the code shorter I want to call the methods after `compact` method chain. But it seems there is only little tricky way to do it,I'll go with simple way. Thanks you for your advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby, you can do multiple assignments in one line:

```
size, sum = a.size, a.sum
```

It doesn't make it more readable, though.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
methods = [:size, :max, :min, :first, :last]

methods.map { |m| a.send m }
  #=> [4, 4, 1, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
size, sum = a.size, a.reduce { |a,b| a = a + b }
```

Comment: `reduce` (or `inject`) is the general form of `sum`. Why use the former when the latter makes directly clear what it does?

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke I think `sum` only works in rails.  Not in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers are correct, but if OP was actually concerned about walking the array multiple times, then `array.size` does not walk the array, it merely returns the length, thus there is no saving from a oneliner in that regard.

On the other hand, if `size` was just an example and the question is more about making multiple operations on an array in one go, then try something like this:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

product,sum = arr.inject([1,0]){|sums,el| [sums[0]*el, sums[1]+el]}
# => [720, 21]
```

That is, inject the array with multiple initial values for the results and then calculate new value for every element.